# Use Machine learning to predict the prices of used car

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis, prediction

I have a large table of used cars.
The header looks like this:

```
maker  | model | year | kilometers | transmission | gas_type | price
```

I made a prediction model, that work like this: every time I wanted to know the price of a car, I filtered the data by maker and model, and then I run a quadratic Regression, using year and kilometers as parameters.

The results are OK, but not for every car.

The problem is that there are different "versions" for the same maker and model.
(It is not the same a FULL version than a simple version, or 4WD, or Leather Seats, etc. )

How can I identify the differences? Can I use some kind of clustering to identify different version between cars with the same model and maker.

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: Clustering will make even more mistakes. It will try to merge similar models.

Answer (score 0):

That's not a clustering problem, just a sub-model feature.  Also, you might want to differentiate between a sub-model (standard, Luxury Edition, hatchback, etc.) from model-independent features (4WD, leather seats, premium sound system, sun roof, etc.).  The sub-model would likely be a single feature (text column), while the options would be individual features (Boolean column).

**UPDATE AFTER OP CLARIFICATION**

I see: those features are *output*, not *input*.

Yes, you can use clustering.  However, that may or may not identify sub-models (your "version").  If you cluster only observations that have very similar use (kilometeres) and all other features equal, you will find *some* useful clustering.  However, this will work only to the extent that the version is a major factor in the remaining price variation.  You may find that your clustering is also affected by geographic region and other factors.

Comment: I do not have the version data, as I show on my table headers. I am asking for a way to infer this information.